# functions with if else statements using prompt

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement

So I have been racking my brain why this doesn't work, I am sure that I am over thinking it .  So the main thing I am trying is to create a JavaScript function “myGame” which takes game Object and returns some custom message so that when the prompt is left undefined its should say please provide your fav game

My attempt;

```js
let game = prompt('What is your fav game');
function myGame(game){
    if(game === undefined){
        console.log('Pls provide your fav game');
    }else{
        console.log(`My fav game is ${game}`)
    }
}
myGame(game);
```

Comment: The return value of [prompt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt) is never `undefined`.

Comment: So what is the problem you are having with this code? What do you enter? What did you expect to happen and what did actually happen?

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use like this:

```
if(prompt('What is your fav game')){
  console.log(`My fav game is ${game}`)
}else{
  console.log('Pls provide your fav game');  
}
```

If user cancels the prompt, it goes to else block. Alternatively, use `if (!prompt()){}` to better implement it checks (user sets the value):

```
if(!prompt('What is your fav game')){
  console.log('Pls provide your fav game');        
}else{
  console.log(`My fav game is ${game}`)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the `prompt()` docs:

> Return value
> A string containing the text entered by the user, or `null`.

So you'll need to check for `null`, not `undefined`.

If you press 'ok' right away, the value will be an empty string (`''`), so use `!game` to check for all `false` values

```js
let game = prompt('What is your fav game');

function myGame(game){
    if (!game){
        console.log('Pls provide your fav game');
    } else{
        console.log(`My fav game is ${game}`)
    }
}
myGame(game);
```